# WPF DataBinding to control properties

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have an issue whereby I am not receiving updates through my bindings.

I have a label which is bound to the ExtentWidth of the TextBox property via the DataContext.

My binding initially works and displays the value of 0 in the label however it does not update after this.

ExtentWidth is a read only property, I'm not sure if this affects the binding in any way but I have a label the binds to the text when it is set so I know it can receive updates. (button updates text and label is updated)

below is some code to demonstrate my issue.

Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestHarnesses.Views.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Content="{Binding}"></ContentPresenter>
            <Label x:Name="lblExtentWidth" 
               Content="{Binding ExtentWidth, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblText" 
               Content="{Binding Text, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <Button Content="Different Jibber Jabber" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestHarnesses.Views
{
    ///
    <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    ///</summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TextBox tb = new TextBox(){Text = "Jibber Jabber"};
            this.TestTextBox = tb;
        }


        public TextBox TestTextBox
        {
            get { return (TextBox)GetValue(TestTextBoxProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TestTextBoxProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TestTextBox.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TestTextBoxProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TestTextBox", typeof(TextBox), typeof(Window1), new PropertyMetadata(OnTestTextBoxProperty));

        private static void OnTestTextBoxProperty(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((Window1) d).DataContext = (TextBox) e.NewValue;
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TestTextBox.Text = "Different Jibber Jabber";
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your View is not being notified about changes to the ExtentWidth property because ExtentWidth is not a DependencyProperty, nor does the TextBox class implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  Also, there does not appear to be a corresponding Changed event associated with this property.

If you want to update your view automatically with the most recent ExtentWidth then you'll need to listen to a different property/event (perhaps the SizeChanged event?) which gets updated simultaneously.